# How to reject oversize file with Dropzone component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-dropzone

I'm using `Dropzone` component of `React-Dropzone` with Nextjs and TypeScript.

- I want to reject the upload if the file size is over 30MB (`30000000` Bytes). The reject message could be whatever at this point.
- Currently, when dropping a big file into the zone - this error appears:

[image: error]

I saw that there is a property called `onDropRejected` to use with `Dropzone` component in this [documentation](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#src) but how can we use this one instead of running into the error like above?

**Here's how my UI looks like:**

[image: error]

**My code:**

```
type Props = {
  name?: string;
  isError?: boolean;
  onChange?: (id: string) => void;
};

export const FileUploader = ({ name, isError, onChange }: Props) => {
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const [nameFile, setNameFile] = useState<string>('File format: CSV Maximum upload size: 30MB');
  const [currId, setCurrId] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    name && setNameFile(name);
  }, [name]);

  const handleDrop = async (acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
    setUploading(true);
    const file = acceptedFiles[0];
    const res = await AssetApis.create(file, AssetResourceType.marketingAction);
    if (res.id) {
      setNameFile(file.name);
      onChange?.(res.id);
      currId && (await AssetApis.remove(currId));
      setCurrId(res.id);
    }
    setUploading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropzone
        onDrop={handleDrop}
        multiple={false}
        accept={['image/*', 'text/csv']}
        disabled={uploading}
        maxSize={30000000}>
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
          <div
            {...getRootProps({ className: 'dropzone' })}
            className='flex items-center w-full h-40 text-center'>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <div
              className={classNames(
                'rounded flex h-full items-center justify-center flex-col flex-1 border border-dashed text-gray-700 mr-2.5 py-6',
                isError ? 'border-danger' : 'border-gray'
              )}>
              <Icon name='upload' size={20} />
              <div className='mb-2.5 text-medium'>Drag and drop to upload</div>
              <button
                type='button'
                className='px-2.5 border-gray-700 border rounded-full text-small px-3 py-0.5'>
                Select file
              </button>
              <div className='mt-2 text-gray-500 text-small'>{nameFile}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Dropzone>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add a function validator :

```
const fileValidator = (file) => {

if (file.size > 30000000) {

  return {
    code: "size-too-large",
    message: `file is larger than 30MB`,
  };
}

return null;
}
```

And then, add your function in your useDropZone :

```
 const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragAccept, isDragReject } =
useDropzone({
  onDrop,
  validator: fileValidator,
});
```